# ChartJS for 1 and 0 values display true or false

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, vue-chartjs

So I have a chart, with a dataset between 0 - 1 (this reffers wether we have stock or not on a specific date) and withing the chart, instead of printing 1 or 0 for each date, I want it to display Yes or No, or at least True / False

https://nimb.ws/W9CVKI - here you have the current way it displays the data

```
{
      "labels": [
        "23.02.2019",
        "24.02.2019",
        "25.02.2019",
        "26.02.2019",
        "27.02.2019",
        "28.02.2019",
        "01.03.2019",
        "02.03.2019"
      ],
      "datasets": [
        {
          "label": "Stock evolution",
          "lineTension": 0,
          "borderColor": "#37a1eb",
          "backgroundColor": "transparent",
          "pointBackgroundColor": "#fff",
          "data": [
            1,
            1,
            1,
            0,
            1,
            0,
            1,
            1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate the desired result along the yAxes, use something similar to this:

```
yAxes:[{
    ticks:{
        callback:function(value,index,values){
            if (value == 1) return "True";
            if (value == 0) return "False";
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

For later version of chart.js the code is

```
y:{
    ticks:{
        callback:function(value,index,values){
            if (value == 1) return "True";
            if (value == 0) return "False";
        }
    }
}
```